# issue with the replacement value if the date is null in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I have a date field and few of the records are null.

my date field is called LSF.EarliestFrom

when I use this code

```
isnull(LSF.EarliestFrom,'') as LSFDateAppliesFrom
```

the output comes as 1900-01-01.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You *did* pass an empty string. That maps to 1900-01-01. If you want a different value, specify it

Comment: That is because your datatype is date/datetime. And an implicit conversion happens. When an empty string is converted to a date it is 1900-01-01. perhaps you should use NULL instead.?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, an empty string on a `date` field will display the default date of `1900-01-01`

If you really need a blank, you will have to cast or convert the column to a string:

```
ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(10),LSF.EarliestFrom),'') as LSFDateAppliesFrom
```

I wouldn't recommend this unless it's purely for display purposes.  Working with dates stored as strings is a bummer.

Comment: It will work, because converting DATETIME(NULL) to VARCHAR(NULL) will result in NULL and the ISNULL function will use the result of that conversion. But it is not the nicest solution, if this is just to show empty string in a UI, then handle it in the UI.

Comment: There isn't always a UI.  I've done this many times in ad-hoc or job based reporting, where *you* know that NULL/1900-01-01 doesn't make any difference, but it's worth the extra seconds to avoid confusing an executive down the line.

Comment: I know, this is why I have the `if` keyword in that sentence. In some cases, you cannot avoid doing presentation layer related things in the database, but try to do so whenever is possible.

Answer (score 0):

The conversion is the thing here, you are trying to display *DateTime* and *Varchar* in the same column

In this case you have to only show Varchar if you want to show date and blank (not null)

You could use this [CONCAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql) function that will parse your *Date* or any other data type to *Varchar*

```
DECLARE @date DATE
SELECT CONCAT(@date,'')
```

CONCAT with format

```
SELECT CONCAT(FORMAT(@date,'MM/dd/yyyy'),'')
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work if you want black in place of NULL

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (ID INT, Dates DATETIME)
    INSERT INTO @T VALUES
    (1,GETDATE()),
    (2,GETDATE()),
    (3,NULL),
    (4,GETDATE()),
    (5,GETDATE()),
    (6,NULL),
    (7,GETDATE());

    SELECT
    ID,
    Dates,
    ISNULL(CAST(CAST(Dates AS DATE) AS VARCHAR(10)),'')
    FROM @T
```